# What is this version of Visual Studio - ".... 4462 QFE"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version, visual-studio-2008-sp1, windows-mobile-6.5

Develop a project in VS for Windows Mobile 6.5.
The project was developed on my machine.

When I try to view a form of the project on another machine with a normal VS (2008 SP1) he accuses interface error. The error occurs not only on my machine.

The version of VS installed on my machine is: QFE Version 9.0.30729.4462
What update is this: ".... 4462 QFE"??

Comment: The second biggest mistake from Microsoft, I just had the same issue and found your post. thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You installed Microsoft SQL Server R2, it updates the version to .4462 QFE